# why Leaflet throw me this Error when im renderin in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, leaflet

i tried to find any solution of my code because im having a big problem with Leaflet right now, im trying to render some information directly on the map, he render but i dont know why when i want to show the info o reload the page doesnt works.. this is my code:

```
  const [allotmenDevice, setAllotmenDevice] = useState({} as any) 

/// i bring the info from the server using allotment

  const loadAllotment = (deviceId: any) => {
     this function===> allotment(deviceId).then( data => {
            if (data.error){
                setError(data.error)
            } else {
                setAllotmenDevice(data)
            }
        })
    }
```

After i use useEffect to save the state from the function :

```
 useEffect (() => {
        const AllotmentId = props.match.params.id
        loadAllotment(AllotmentId)    
        
    },[props])
```

Then i look if the info is here using a span

```
 const sideMenuDeviceInfo = () => (
        <>
            
            <div className="sm-wrapper">
                    <div>
                    <span>Longitude: {allotmenDevice.lastLocation?.longitude}</span>
                    <br/>
                    <span>Latitude: {allotmenDevice.lastLocation?.latitude}</span>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
```

Result:

```
Longitude: 48.929569
Latitude: -0.861133
```

and yes is here after im trying to render this info like this using Leaflet:

```
            <MapContainer center={[allotmenDevice.lastLocation?.longitude, allotmenDevice.lastLocation?.latitude]} zoom={15} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <Marker position={[allotmenDevice.lastLocation?.longitude, allotmenDevice.lastLocation?.latitude]}>
                    <Popup>
                    <Link to="/data">Data</Link>
                    </Popup>
                </Marker>
                </MapContainer>
            );
```

works! but if i reload the page throw me an Error:

Error: Invalid LatLng object: (undefined, undefined):

```
new LatLng
C:/Users/troya/Desktop/src/geo/LatLng.js:32
  29 | 
  30 | export function LatLng(lat, lng, alt) {
  31 |  if (isNaN(lat) || isNaN(lng)) {
> 32 |      throw new Error('Invalid LatLng object: (' + lat + ', ' + lng + ')');
  33 |  }
  34 | 
  35 |  // @property lat: Number
```

so if anyone can help me !

Comment: Is your `<MapContainer>` always rendered, even if your variable `allotmenDevice` does not contain coordinates?

Comment: Are you sure that `allotmenDevice.lastLocation?.latitude` is set

Comment: @ghybs have to render because i use useEffect to bring the coordinates.. and yes always is render

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you unconditionally render your Map and Marker, even if you do not have the coordinates which Leaflet needs to set your map view and Marker position.

A simple solution would be to display the map and Marker only when these coordinates are available:

```
((typeof allotmenDevice.lastLocation !== "undefined") &&
  <MapContainer
    center={[allotmenDevice.lastLocation.longitude, allotmenDevice.lastLocation.latitude]}
    zoom={15}
  >
    <Marker
      position={[allotmenDevice.lastLocation.longitude, allotmenDevice.lastLocation.latitude]}
    >
    </Marker>
  </MapContainer>
)
```